# Як перекласти "matinée" з французької

Tags: словотворення

Давно вже точаться суперечки як перекласти з російської *утренник*. Я подивися, що англійською це зазвичай перекладають як *matinee*. Походить це слово з французької:

```
matin    -->    matinée    -->   matinee
ранок           ранок
                (як період 
                активності)
```

Мені цікаво чи є в українською мовою переклад для ранку як для пероду активності. Це буде *ранкування* чи як? Чи є загальне правило такого словотворення?

Comment: У білоруській мові є _ранішнік_, нам би теж щось схоже пригодилося б - наприклад **ранішник**

Comment: Або "вранішник".

Comment: СУМ-11 має таке тлумачення для слова ["Ранок"](http://sum.in.ua/s/ranok): "2. Публічне ранкове зібрання, де виконуються літературні, музичні та інші твори. *Полтавське громадянство влаштовувало недільні літературні ранки для бідного населення і для учнів (Збірник про Кропивницького, 1955, 312).*" На [Форум.словник.уа](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t908.html) також пропонують "святковий ранок": "Часом це нагадувало святковий ранок з перевдяганнями в дитячому садку. 
Юрій Андрухович "Московіада".

Answer (score 4):

[Словник української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/ranok) в 11 томах. — Том 8, 1977. — [Сторінка 451.](http://sum.in.ua/p/8/451/1)

> 2. Публічне ранкове зібрання, де виконуються літературні, музичні та інші твори. *Полтавське громадянство влаштовувало недільні літературні ранки для бідного населення і для учнів* (Збірник про Кропивницького, 1955, 312).

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник](//r2u.org.ua/html/announcement.html)

> [Утренник](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&highlight=on)
>
> 2. (*театральне*) ранок, ранковий спектакль:
>
>    - детский утренник — дитячий ранок.

---

*Порівняйте.* [Вечір.](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/814/)

*Від себе.* Є *вечірка*, себто пестливе від *вечір*. Тому ніц не заважає зробити [*раночок*](http://sum.in.ua/s/ranochok).

Comment: Може тоді подібно до Петриківка - *раноківка*? Або ж якщо йти від слова рано, тоді подібно до гаївка - *ранівка*?

Answer (score -1):

Можливо спробувавти перекласти як **ранковик**? нажаль не можу обгрунтувати докладно.